# Applescript : user interface scripting, how to "tell" a process when two processes of the same name exist?

Tags: process, applescript

I've been making this applescript app to automate the behaviour of an app (TimeFactory2) which doesn't support scripting. So, I end up doing UI scripting with it. Thing is, for my use, I want several instances of the app to run simultaneously, so I've copied the .app and I launch every copy (the point is to take advantage of multithreading, each instance using a core on my computer - the app is very cpu-intensive but doesn't support multithreading). So I ended up initially with this code (sorry for the french comments):

```
tell application "TimeFactory2 Demo"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "TimeFactory2 Demo"
    repeat with extension in extensions_list
        -- pomme-O pour sélectionner un fichier à ajouter
        repeat until window "Open" exists
            keystroke "o" using {command down}
        end repeat
        -- pomme-shift-g pour entrer un path de fichier
        keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
        -- on copie dans le clipboard le path du fichier à séléctionner
        tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to (audio_file_path & extension)
        -- on colle dans la box
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        -- enter enter
        keystroke return
        keystroke return
    end repeat
    -- dans le cas où la dernière selection de fichier n'aurait rien donné, on fait deux fois escape pour sortir des fenêtre de sélection de fichier
    key code 53
    key code 53
end tell
end tell
```

... which does work well when only one instance of TF2 is running.
However, when running 2+ instances, everything breaks; after thorough testing I understood that for some reason, as for the line :

```
repeat until window "Open" exists
```

... the script cannot tell anymore if the window open exists (even though it does), and thus emulates a command-o keystroke on and on. I assumed the whole thing came from the fact that the processes' names are the same for all instances of the app, so the code

```
tell process "TimeFactory2 Demo"
```

was ambiguous for the system. I then searched a way to take off the ambiguity and tried to single out each process with its unix id (here is an example with an instance whose uid is 629):

```
set TF2_process_list to every process whose unix id is 629

set TF2_process to item 1 of TF2_process_list

tell (process TF2_process)
    repeat until window "Open" exists
        keystroke "o" using {command down}
        delay 2
    end repeat
end tell
```

which got me the following error :

```
error "System Events error : impossible to render {} as integer type." number -1700 from {} to integer
```

... and I'm stuck there. Pretty much toured the internet for solutions to this problem, but I'm still clueless. Anyone see any solution? Or maybe a different approach to the whole script that would avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to discriminate the processes : with the syntax :

```
set processID to id of first process whose name is "Time Factory 2 Demo"

tell process id processID
    etc.
```

I can "tell" the different processes based on their id, which is unique.

To get the ids to each process, I can use the process' "file" property, which includes the name of the .app bundle which IS different depending on which copy of the application I'm trying to control.

Answer (score 0):

Regular application bundles are not set up to run like this (e.g. they will all try to use the same preferences file), so you might try changing the bundle identifier of the copies (add a numerical suffix, for example) and use these bundle identifiers in your tell statements instead of the application name.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if it will make a difference, but normally it would be 'tell application process' not 'tell process':

tell application "System Events"
tell application process "TimeFactory2 Demo"